# Why Rails (current 4.0) fails to interpret nested JSON (from a HTTP POST)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, post, nested

I am writing a simple client server application (using only JSON API) with Ruby (client) and Rails (server).

When trying to create a game from client, I am using:

```
    uri = URI.parse(url)
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
    request.set_form_data({"tttgame" => {"name" => "Marius"}})

    resp = http.request(request)
```

On server side (tttgames_controller.rb) I have:

```
    # POST /tttgames
    # POST /tttgames.json
    def create
      @tttgame = Tttgame.new(tttgame_params)
      ...
    end
    ...
    def tttgame_params
      params.require(:tttgame).permit(:name)
    end
```

Logs on server are:

```
    Started POST "/tttgames.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-05 12:58:44 +0300
    Processing by TttgamesController#create as JSON
      Parameters: {"tttgame"=>"{\"name\"=>\"Marius\"}"}
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms

    NoMethodError (undefined method `stringify_keys' for "{\"name\"=>\"Marius\"}":String):
      app/controllers/tttgames_controller.rb:33:in `create'
```

How can I fix this? All examples from the Internet are looking the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both methods `set_form_data` and `post_form` are encoding data using format x-www-form-urlencoded. Check [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/Net/HTTPHeader/set_form_data). 
Examples that are provided do not contain nested hashes.

I have found [here](http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html) an example, under the REST methods section, which works very well.

Thus, in order to get on server a valid structure with nested hashes, the client should use square brackets:

```
    uri = URI.parse(url)
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
    request.set_form_data({"tttgame[name]" => “Marius”)
    resp = http.request(request)
```

or much simpler:

```
    uri = URI.parse(url)
    resp = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, {"tttgame[name]" => “Marius”})
```

This will generate on server

```
    Parameters: {"tttgame"=>{"name"=>"Marius"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do this instead. It's even more compact.

```
uri = URI.parse(url)
resp = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, "tttgame" => {"name" => "Marius"})
```

From http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#label-POST+with+Multiple+Values

Comment: It has the same effect like `Net::HTTP::Post.set_form_data`

Answer (score -2):

**UPDATE**: In addition, your String is not a valid JSON. It needs to be `"{\"name\":\"Marius\"}"` instead.

You need to parse that response, because right now it is a `String` (`"{\"name\"=>\"Marius\"}"`) but you actually need a `Hash` (`{"name" => "Marius"}`).

Therefore `#stringify_keys` fails because it is a method that [operates](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html#method-i-stringify_keys) on a `Hash`.

So do a:

```
@tttgame = Tttgame.new(JSON.parse(tttgame_params))
```

instead. This will turn your serialized JSON response into a `Hash` from a `String`.

Comment: By doing what you suggest i am getting the following error: _JSON::ParserError (757: unexpected token at '{"name"=>"Marius"}'):
  app/controllers/tttgames_controller.rb:31:in `create'_ Looks like **JSON.parse** fails to interpret rocket sign (=>) since it is not a valid token for a JSON document

Comment: @marius_gu yes, overlooked this. Updated my answer.

Comment: Rigth! Then the question is: How client should format the message, so the server would get it in a valid JSON format like `"{\"name\":\"Marius\"}"`?

Comment: @marius_gu The client should only be concerned about sending a valid JSON request. If it does, the backend will properly handle it (ie. parse it).

Comment: Pls give an example in my case, since putting on client `request.set_form_data({"tttgame" => {"name" => "Marius"}})` will not arrive as a valid JSON on server